# Single-spa angular app child routing doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-routing, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have set up a single-spa root-config app and other 2 child apps implemented in angular (using [parcels](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/parcels-overview)). And I'm trying to navigate to child app routes from root app, it works for the first route `/app1`, but from that if I want to navigate to `/app1/search` or `/app1/details` it doesn't load the associated component, although url is changed.

If I initially hit `/app1/search` it loads search component, but after that if I try to navigate to other routes like `/app1/<any-route>` it changes the url, but doesn't load the components.

root-config app.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/app1" routerLinkActive="active">App1 Home</a>
<a routerLink="/app1/search" routerLinkActive="active">App1 Search</a>
<a routerLink="/app1/details" routerLinkActive="active">App1 Details</a>
<a routerLink="/app2" routerLinkActive="active">App2 Home</a>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App1 route module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app1',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent
      }, {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }]
  }, {
    path: '**',
    component: EmptyRouteComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app1',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'app1/search',
    component: SearchComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'app1/details',
    component: DetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: EmptyRouteComponent
  }
];
```

if you want to create a children then add

**home.component.html**

```html
<a routerLink="/search" routerLinkActive="active">App1 Search</a>
<a routerLink="/details" routerLinkActive="active">App1 Details</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then use the router like below.

````js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app1',
    component: HomeComponent
    children: [
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent
      }, {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }]
  }, {
    path: '**',
    component: EmptyRouteComponent
  }
];```
````

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, but no luck. Also, I want to be able to navigate to app1/search and app2/search from the root config app of single-spa. I have tried adding router-outlet within child app for routing like /details you pointed above, but that's not the behaviour I want. If you have any input, please do share.

Comment: Can you tell me how your app is structured? Looking at the router config I think you have 2 apps and you want to create separate routes for apps.
App1 and App2 have seperate child routes and separate home page. rit?

Comment: There are 2 apps - app1 and app2, both of them have routes configured like mentioned in my question. And there's a root-config app which is also implemented in angular and this app acts as a container for the other 2 apps and shows the links that load pages from app1 and app2. I hope this helps

Comment: If you want to access all component in the top most router outlet, then it is better not to use children and use `/app1/details` directly in path property. If you want to make it children then in Home component you can use `<router-outlet>` and in the app component you can call `/app1/details`. Hope this works

Comment: I understand that it should work that way with normal angular app. Since I'm using single-spa framework and the apps are loaded as parcels, it's not working with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you were able your issue, but this will could help you.
As this link mentioned [Configure routes](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular#configure-routes), its important set the `APP_BASE_HREF`

so in your case this will work

`providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app1' }]` in `app-routing.module.ts`

if you set your `APP_BASE_URL` with `/` you'll have to add `/app1` prefix in all links and routes.